# How to open keyboard on button press in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a button and when it is pressed I would like it to open the keyboard and focus on a text input component.

For a minimal code example what I am trying to do is this-

```
      <View>
          <AddSomething
            textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
            addNewItem={this.addItem.bind(this)}
            textInput={this.state.textInput}
            ref={not sure what goes here} //passing these as props to a text input
          />
          <FloatingButton tapToAddHandler={this.onFloatingButtonPress.bind(this)} />
      </View>
```

then some helper function where I handle the button press (this.onFloatingButtonPress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First declare your `AddSomething` as below :

```js
const AddSomething = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <TextInput 
        ref={ref} 
        //your other code
    />
));
```

Now you can use `ref` and able to focus your `AddSomething` component as below:

```js
      <View>
          <AddSomething
            textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
            addNewItem={this.addItem.bind(this)}
            textInput={this.state.textInput}
            ref={(ref) => { this.textInputField = ref }}
          />
          <FloatingButton tapToAddHandler={this.onFloatingButtonPress.bind(this)} />
      </View>
```

Here is your `onFloatingButtonPress` method :

```js
onFloatingButtonPress() {
    this.textInputField.focus();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Proposal a react-hook version :

```js
const inputRef = React.useRef()

return (
  <TextInput ref={inputRef} />
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>
    <Text>Press</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```